# FormRegion null in NewInspector

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto

i'm trying to put in a textbox that I have added to a FormRegion when the mail item os opened. The Textbox exist in the item but when try to assign the category to the textbox y get a null Reference exception because the Formregion1 is null.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private WithEvents inspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        inspectors = Me.Application.Inspectors

    End Sub

    Private Sub inspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector) Handles inspectors.NewInspector

        Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = TryCast(Inspector.CurrentItem, Outlook.MailItem)
        Dim mCat As String
        Dim formRegions As WindowFormRegionCollection = Globals.FormRegions(Inspector)
        mCat = mailItem.Categories
        formRegions.FormRegion1.TextBox1.Text = mCat

    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Would using a task pane instead of a form region be a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the form region was not created for the inspector window at the time when the `NewInspector` event is fired. Instead, I'd recommend handling the [Activate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/inspector-activate-event-outlook) event of the Inspector class where you can do the same operations. You may find the [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.